# PCL: Filtering Point Cloud given 2 line equations

Tags: c++, pcl

Given two line equations in the form y = mx + c all of the points that are not in between of the two lines must be filtered out.

Currently I'm using a pass through filter, which approximately filters out the points. Instead, could this be done more precisely using the two line equations?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a line defined by `y = mx + c1` and another, defined by `y = mx + c2`. As you can see, I assume the `m` coefficient to be identical for both lines, for otherwise the phrase

> all of the points that are not **in between** of the two lines must be filtered out

would be senseless.

Now, sort the lines so that `c2 <= c1`, that is

```
if (c1 < c2) std:;swap(c1, c2);
```

Now you're sure that the `c1` line is equivalent to or above the `c2` line.

Take any point (`xx`, `yy`). Plug `xx` into the equation of the 1st line,
`y = m * xx + c1`. If the result is smaller than `yy`, then (`xx`, `yy`) lies above the `c1` line. You should remove it from the cloud.

Do the same with the c2 line: `y  = m * xx + c2`. If the result is larger than yy, the point (`xx`, `yy`) lies below line `c2` and should be removed from the set.

In other words, you should keep those and only those points (x, y) that satisfy

```
  m * x + c1 >= y and m * x + c2 <= y; // assuming c1 >= c2
```

Example:

Suppose you have `y = x + 3` and y = `x + 1`. Suppose you have a point (2,4). Should you keep it or filter out?

We have `c1` = 3, `c2` = 1. Let's insert 2 to the first line. y = 1*2 + c1 = 5. 5 >= 4. The first test is passed.

Now the second line. y = 1*2 + 1 = 3. 3 <= 4. The second condition is also satisfied. Conclusion: keep it, in full agreement with t he figure.

[image: Two parallel lines]